# Retrieving all entries except who are blocked query

Tags: php

I have following table

```
id  blocked  blocker
1     2        1
2     4        2
3     xx       xx
4     xx       xx
```

Suppose i provide an id 2

1- I want to perform a query in which both first and second result will be output.

I am using following query

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE blocker = :blocker OR blocked=:blocked');
```

WILL THIS WORK?

Now Once I got array of these entries that is

```
$row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Note: It must get all the row because I need their alternative values i-e 1 and 4 in above example.

Secondly using above results, I have another table users. I want to perform a query which will get all entries except 1 and 4 (REFER TO TABLE ABOVE) will be output

```
id  username  password etc
1
2
3
4
```

How can I perform these two queries without using much server resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is wrong... you need to use `OR` instead of `AND` to return both 1 and 2.

`SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE blocker = :blocker OR blocked=:blocked`

Now you can get all the data you need in a single query by using a join:

```
 SELECT u.*, b.* FROM blocks b, users u 
 WHERE (
    b.blocker = :blocker OR b.blocked=:blocked
 ) AND (
   u.id = b.blocker
   OR u.id = b.blocked
 )
```

Be aware that this is potentially going to give you 2 rows corresponding to a single user for example a result could be:

```
id username password etc id blocked blocker
1  user1    *******  **  1   2       1
2  user2    *******  **  1   2       1
2  user2    *******  **  2   4       2
```

If youre not actually after whose been blocked by who, then you dont even need to select the blocks data and you can group or distinct the users so you only get one instance of each:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM users u, blocks b 
 WHERE (
    b.blocker = :blocker OR b.blocked=:blocked
 ) AND (
   u.id = b.blocker
   OR u.id = b.blocked
 )
```

Which would yield a result like:

```
id username password etc
1  user1    *******  **
2  user2    *******  **
```

Comment: i have edited first query :) i think that one is correct, but i am more curious regarding second query.

Comment: Well do you actually need the data from `blocks` for any other reason than selecting the desired data from `users`?

Comment: No, i just need data from blocks to get array of all ids

Comment: But do you only need those id values to query the users?

Comment: When I block someone , my id and its id is saved as blocker and blocked. Now when i call all users, he should not see me nor i should see him. The above query is giving me False instead of returning all list of users.